# Como executar um evento no CodeBehind sendo chamado pelo jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Eu tenho esse código em **Aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite.View.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Projeto para Testes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dvEventos" class="dvEventos">
            <h1>Apenas um teste</h1>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEventoCsharp" CssClass="btnEventoCsharp" Text="Evento C#" OnClick="btnEventoCsharp_Click" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnEventoCsharpByJS" CssClass="btnEventoCsharpByJS" Text="Evento C# by JS" OnClick="btnEventoCsharpByJS_Click" runat="server"  />
            <button id="btnEventoJqueryClick" class="btnEventoJqueryClick">Evento C# by Jquery</button>
            <button id="btnEventoJquery" class="btnEventoJquery">Evento Jquery</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CarregaEventosIndex();
    });

    function CarregaEventosIndex() {
        $('.btnEventoJquery').off('click').on('click', function () {
            alert('Event click by Jquery');
        });

        $('.btnEventoJqueryClick').off('click').on('click', function () {
            $("input[id*=btnEventoCsharpByJS]").click();
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

O arquivo do meu **CodeBehind**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebSite.View
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void MetodoSemParametroChamadoEventosDiferentes()
        {
            string passeiAqui = "sem parametro";
            string evento = passeiAqui;
        }

        /// Evento de Teste
        protected void btnEventoCsharpByJS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MetodoSemParametroChamadoEventosDiferentes();
        }
    }
}
```

Estou utilizando Webforms, e eu preciso chamar um evento do CodeBehind pelo jQuery, no caso, usando esse botão `btnEventoJqueryClick`. Mas tem um porem, se eu usar esse código `$("input[id*=btnEventoCsharpByJS]").click();` pelo console do navegador, usando breakpoint no CodeBehind percebo que o evento é chamado, mas clicando no botão não está sendo chamado o evento. O que estou fazendo de errado? Ou, como posso chamar um evento do CodeBehind pelo jQuery de forma diferente?

Comment: Olhando no console do navegador, aparece alguma requisição de "rede"? Criei um exemplo aqui, exatamente como você colocou aí e esta funcionando.

Comment: Para executar qualquer coisa que esteja do lado do servidor pelo browser, você vai precisar fazer uma requisição para o mesmo, um GET ou POST por exemplo.

Comment: Te ajudou a solução?

Comment: Consegui usando outra solução

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar essa questão coloque um `<input type="hidden" />` igual exemplo abaixo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
```

dentro da tag `<form></form>`, esses dois `input` vão servir para que o servidor saiba o que é para fazer, e se tiver algum argumento para passar que também tenha isso para execução de qualquer método no `codebehind`, toda a requisição nesse caso é com o verbo `POST`que é o padrão.

A pagina `.aspx` tem o seguinte resultado:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication1.Test"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />     
    <button id="btnDateTime">Evento Data e Hora</button>    
    <div>      
      <asp:Literal ID="TxtDataNow" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
      const theForm = document.getElementById("form1");
      if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnDateTime").click(function () {
        __doPostBack('btnDateTime', '');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Foi criado um código em `javascript` com o nome de `__doPostBack` que tem a intenção real de enviar as informações para o seu `back-end` sendo as informações de ação e argumentos se assim for necessário.

---

No código dessa página teria alguma modificações onde precisa saber qual botão foi clicado e o que é para ser feito, no caso `__EVENTTARGET` é o nome do botão que foi clicado e nesse caso aciona o método `ActionBtn()` alterando o valor do `<Literal>`:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        var __EVENTTARGET = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
        if (__EVENTTARGET == "btnDateTime")
        {
           ActionBtn();
        }
     }
  }
  protected void ActionBtn()
  {
     TxtDataNow.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss");
  }
}
```

---

Não sei até que ponto isso precise ser feito assim, quando eu usava esse estilo nunca fiz nada parecido, no máximo quando era um WebService com um método `static` para trazer informações para o `Front`, tem que verificar se isso realmente é necessário, talvez, em certos casos raros sim, mas, na maioria um simples componente com o seu evento normal de `PostBack` já resolve o problema.

Nesse exemplo é usado um `button` normal, porque, a maioria dos exemplos são vinculados a componentes pertence a `toolbox` para que o evento dele seja refeito de outra forma, nesse não ele faz realmente o evento. Se tiver algum problema com o [EventValidation](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation?view=netframework-4.8) inclua no inicio da página na primeira linha um configuração: `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" ...`.

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation Método](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerforeventvalidation?view=netframework-4.8)
- [ASP.NET - EnableEventValidation="false" OR EnableEventValidation="true"](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4922918/EnableEventValidationequals-false-OR-EnableEventVa.aspx)
- [jQuery - Chamando métodos do lado do servidor usando JavaScript e jQuery em ASP .NET](http://www.macoratti.net/13/09/aspn_ss1.htm)
- [Como usar __doPostBack ()](https://www.it-swarm.net/pt/c%23/como-usar-dopostback/969295706/)
- [How to capture submit event using jQuery in an ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230573/how-to-capture-submit-event-using-jquery-in-an-asp-net-application)